# How do I escape a single quote using C# string.Replace to use in HighCharts?

Tags: c#, regex, highcharts, escaping

In my c# application I am using user input to fill elements in HighCharts. The issue that I am running into is when a user types `customer's` it causes the application to break unless it is escaped by typing a <kbd>\</kbd> before a <kbd>'</kbd>.

Here is the section in the Highcharts that I am filling in with the user input:

```
subtitle: {
    text: '<%=strDescription%>'
},
```

When adding records, instead of telling my users to type an <kbd>\</kbd> before typing a <kbd>'</kbd> I want to do this for them automatically for them when I pull it out of the database and assign it to a variable. Here is what I have tried:

```
strDescription = reader1.GetString(0);
strDescription.Replace("'", "\'");
```

When I remove the slash from the user input it causes the application to break as if the string was not escaped. Note the following error:

```
subtitle: {
    text: 'This goal will be set once we have bench-marked the first quarter's results.'
},
```

How do I escape the single quote properly?

Comment: Not sure about highcharts, but an `@` before the string will make it a literal.  Can you put double quotes around your text variable instead of single?

Comment: @paqogomez I resolved my own issue by using 
`strDescription = reader1.GetString(0).Replace("'", "\\'");` However I have to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer.

Comment: Glad you found the answer, though I would suggest that doing string replaces on data will end up biting you down the road.  Its always better to find a way to not have to manipulate the user data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this to resolve my issue.

```
strDescription = reader1.GetString(0).Replace("'", "\\'");
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is Invert the quotes - '' to ""

```
subtitle: {
    text: "<%=strDescription%>"
},
```

Comment: I found a different way using `string.replace` but would like to mark this one as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead.

```
(?=')
```

And then replace by `\`.

Comment: My scripting is done in the codebehind. I am trying to add the escape when the string is extracted from the database. Using the lookahead, is this possible? If so, can you show me an example?